# Excel column cell data match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

In Excel if a cell contain a certain String how can i compare and replace it.

I have a column in the Excel file called **1st contact person** and all i want is if in the column **2nd Contact Person** if it's says **Same as 1st Contact Person** than replace the name with the correct name else do nothing.

I have tried this query --

```
=IF(EXACT([1st Contact Person], "Same as 1st Contact Person"),[2nd Contact Person],"")
```

Excel file ---

```
1st Contact Person   2nd Contact Person
Chris Johnsson       Same as 1st Contact Person
Henrik Johnsson      Same as 1st Contact Person
Johanna Nilsson      Christofer Hanssen
```

No luck with my query !!

Can anyone tell me where i am doing something wrong .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Vba like:
Suppose 1st contact Person is in column E and 2nd contact person is in column F
then with vba:

```
Sub sample()

    Dim TotalRows As Integer

    TotalRows = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To TotalRows

    If Range("F" & i).Value = "Same as 1st Contact Person" Then

    Range("F" & i).Value = Range("E" & i).Value

    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will loop over Column F and look for text "Same as 1st Contact Person" if found it will replace the text with the name of the person in Column E

Hope this helps

Comment: Since Range.Value is an array you can cast `Match` on it , or another(better because of `FindNext` and because a range is returned) option cast `Find` method. Just to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `B2` cell

```
=IF($A2="","",IF($C2="Same as 1st Contact Person",$A2,IF(LEN($C2)>0,$C2,"")))
```

[image]